# Acceder a una propiedad de un objeto a partir de un string

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Tengo el siguiente objeto:

```
form: {
    validate: false,
    valid: true,
    fields: {

        nombre : {
            value: 'Pablo',
            errors: [
            ],
            rules: [
            ],
        },

        hours : {
            value: {
                start: '10:00 AM',
                end: '11:00 AM',
            },
            errors: [
            ],
            rules: [
            ],
        },
        
    },
},
```

Quiero acceder a la propiedad `form->fields->hours->value`
A pulso se puede obtener se la siguiente manera: `form.fields.hours.value.end`

Pero quiero acceder dinámicamente a la propiedad, con un string. Ej, algo como lo siguiente:

```
form['fields.hours.value.end']
```

Pero esto obviamente intentara buscar una propiedad llamada **fields.hours.value.end** (cuyo cual no existe y me devolvera un **undefined** )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El acceso por índice es solo para una propiedad, los puntos dentro de una cadena no separan objetos. Esa forma que estás intentando solo funcionaría en caso de que `form` tuviera la propiedad definida entre comillas: `"fields.hours.value.end"`

Debes separar cada propiedad: `form['fields']['hours']['value']['end']`

Si necesitas hacerlo con una sola cadena, debes crear una función que reciba el objeto y la cadena, separando cada propiedad y analizando si existe o no.

```js
let form = {
    validate: false,
    valid: true,
    "fields.hours.value.end": "Agregada para probar",
    fields: {

        nombre : {
            value: 'Pablo',
            errors: [
            ],
            rules: [
            ],
        },

        hours : {
            value: {
                start: '10:00 AM',
                end: '11:00 AM',
            },
            errors: [
            ],
            rules: [
            ],
        },
        
    },
};

console.log(form["fields.hours.value.end"]);
console.log(form['fields']['hours']['value']['end']);

// Función para buscar usando solo una cadena
function propFromString(obj, str) {
    // Valor a devolver
    let ret = obj;
    // Separar por puntos
    let props = str.split('.');
    // Recorrer arreglo
    for(let i = 0; i < props.length; i ++) {
        // Analizar si el objeto tiene la propiedad
        if(!ret.hasOwnProperty(props[i])) {
            // No la tiene, devolver valor nulo
            return null;
        }
        // Actualizar objeto con la propiedad
        ret = ret[props[i]];
    }
    // Devolver objeto o valor obtenido
    return ret;
}
// Obtener el objeto horas
console.log(propFromString(form, "fields.hours"));
// Obtener el valor de inicio de horas
console.log(propFromString(form, "fields.hours.value.start"));
```

Answer (score 1):

La primera respuesta es acertada y funciona. Sin embargo por aca dejo una con ES5, sencilla.

```js
const form = {
    validate: false,
    valid: true,
    fields: {

        nombre : {
            value: 'Pablo',
            errors: [
            ],
            rules: [
            ],
        },

        hours : {
            value: {
                start: '10:00 AM',
                end: '11:00 AM',
            },
            errors: [
            ],
            rules: [
            ],
        },
        
    },
}

const propFromString = ({obj, str}) => {

        const props = str.split('.');
    
        return props.reduce((old, curr)=>{
        return old[curr];
    },obj);
}

console.log('propFromString',propFromString({
        obj: form,
        str: 'fields.hours.value.start',
}))
```

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, se simplifica con `.reduce()`.